# Dockerfile запуск nginx + php-fpm

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Есть такой *Dockerfile*:

```
FROM zercle/docker-ubuntu

# Update OS
RUN apt update && apt -y full-upgrade

# Install PHP
RUN apt-add-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php \
    && apt update \
    && apt -y install \
    php-ssh2 \
    php7.1-cli \
    php7.1-curl \
    php7.1-fpm \
    php7.1-gd \
    php7.1-gmp \
    php7.1-imap \
    php7.1-json \
    php7.1-ldap \
    php7.1-mbstring \
    php7.1-mcrypt \
    php7.1-mysql \
    php7.1-opcache \
    php7.1-pgsql \
    php7.1-readline \
    php7.1-snmp\
    php7.1-soap \
    php7.1-sqlite3 \
    php7.1-xml \
    php7.1-xmlrpc \
    php7.1-xsl \
    php7.1-zip \
    php-memcached \
    php-mysqlnd-ms \
    php-imagick
RUN apt-get install -y nginx
RUN systemctl enable php7.1-fpm.service
RUN service nginx start
RUN service php7.1-fpm start

# Clean file
RUN apt-get autoclean

EXPOSE  9000

#ENTRYPOINT ["/etc/init.d/nginx", "restart", ";", "/etc/init.d/php7.1-fpm", "restart"]
#CMD /etc/init.d/php7.1-fpm restart && /etc/init.d/nginx restart
#CMD service php7.1-fpm start
CMD /etc/init.d/nginx restart
#CMD ["/etc/init.d/nginx", "restart", "&&", "/etc/init.d/php7.1-fpm", "restart"]
```

Так вот соль в том, что *nginx* & *php-fpm* не запускается при `$ docker-compose up -d`.

Все рабочее, поскольку если "из-под" контейнера запустить *nginx&php-fpm* - все работает отлично.

Вопрос следующий - как мне "автоматически" поднять внутри docker-контейнера нужные сервисы?

Answer (score 2):

Docker подразумевает только один процесс в качестве "отправной точки" контейнера, в то время как вы пытаетесь запустить несколько. Это не значит, что в контейнере нельзя запустить несколько процессов, просто контейнер рождается из одного процесса и вместе с ним умирает. Это не очень сильно отличается от операционной системы, у которой ровно так же есть один исходный процесс (init), который занимается запуском всех остальных.

Поэтому ENTRYPOINT и CMD - это все лишь составляющие одного процесса: будучи конкатенированными, они представляют собой массив строк, первая из которых указывает запускаемый бинарник, а все остальные - аргументы запуска. Поэтому де-факто ";" и "&&" - не более чем передаваемые скрипту строки. Какое-то отдельное значение они имеют только в shell, среде исполнения команд, докер же оперирует процессами, и у него таких понятий нет.

Поэтому если вы хотите запустить несколько процессов в контейнере, вам нужен родительский скрипт/бинарник, который запустит их и будет жить, пока оба из них не закончатся - или, наоборот, попросит их завершить работу, когда сигнал завершения пришлют ему. Проще всего это сделать с помощью произвольного супервайзера (e.g. supervisord), однако это идет вразрез с философией докера. Докер предлагает [в том числе] заменить собой виртуальные машины, однако благодаря разделяемому ядру контейнеры докера практически ничего не потребляют сверх завернутых в них процессов, и согласно концепции докера следует разделить один контейнер на два (nginx, php-fpm) и запускать их отдельно, осуществляя сообщение по сети.

Answer (score 2):

```
RUN systemctl enable php7.1-fpm.service
RUN service nginx start
RUN service php7.1-fpm start
```

Это лишнее, так как

- **systemd** совершенно не работает (не имеет смысла) в Docker
- вызов **start** запустит процесс только на время сборки

`RUN apt-get autoclean`

В этом вызове так же нет смысла, так как

- Docker **сам чистит** apt кэш в том же слое, где была установка
- все лишние файлы **уже зафиксировались** в слое (если бы Docker не произвел чистку), где была установка, эта команда только увеличит занимаемое место, так как добавит записей "этот файл считать удаленным"

Если **важно поместить именно php-fpm и nginx** в один контейнер, посмотрите как это сделано в контейнере phpMyAdmin

- Dockerfile https://github.com/phpmyadmin/docker/blob/master/Dockerfile
- стартовый скрипт с supervisord https://github.com/phpmyadmin/docker/blob/master/run.sh

Но я бы рекомендовал взять за основу официальный образ php с Apache https://hub.docker.com/_/php/ и его уже дополнять, например так

```
FROM php:apache

RUN a2enmod rewrite \
&& docker-php-ext-install mysqli
```

Либо, если это не приемлимо, запускать два контейнера: `nginx` отдельно и  `php:fpm` отдельно.